# Добавить в объект такую часть кода

Tags: javascript, объекты

Нужно выводить изображение на канвасе через объект, все изображения необходимо добавить в объект. Поскажите, как это сделать?

Вот два изображения которые необходимо "поместить" в объект, для дальнейшнего вызова через  ключ:

```
var left = new Image();
left.src = 'images/left.png';
var right = new Image();
right.src = 'images/right.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  left: () => {
    var left = new Image();
    left.src = 'images/left.png';
    return left;
  },

  right: () => {
    var right = new Image();
    right.src = 'images/right.png';
  }
}

var img1 = obj.left();
var img2 = obj.right();

//Проверяем 
document.body.appendChild(img1);
```

Comment: А можно выводить изображения именно через объект?  Например как-то так: obj[left]

Comment: @Евгений Калайда, можно так: obj['left']()     :)

Comment: А вот так? var left = "left"; obj[left]();

Comment: @Евгений Калайда, можно же это самому попробовать?) Так тоже работает